# Apply OnClickListener() to new Buttons in end scene

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-transitions

My app starts with a single button. Pressing it causes this button to slide down and new buttons to slide in into the same activity. I want to set OnClickListeners to these new buttons so I can use them to launch new activities using intent. The problem is when I try to do so, the app crashes even before it starts.

**My app transitions from this :**

[image: Initial Layout of main activity]

**To this :**

[image: Final scene of main activity]

**MainActivity.java** (Commented part is the code I am trying to apply to the buttons)

```
package com.techpappy.whattoeat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
//import android.support.transition.Fade;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.*;
import android.transition.Slide;
import android.transition.Transition;
import android.transition.TransitionInflater;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
//import com.transitionseverywhere.*;
//import com.transitionseverywhere.Scene;
//import com.transitionseverywhere.TransitionManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button vegbtn, nonvegbtn;
 //   private TextView vegtext, nonvegtext, prefertext;

    ViewGroup container;
    Scene current;
    Button btn;
    Transition mainmenuTrans;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.initial_layout);

        mainmenuTrans = TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.slideinleft);
        container = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.container);
        current = Scene.getSceneForLayout(container, R.layout.scene1, this);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        mainmenuTrans = TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.slideinleft);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                TransitionManager.go(current, mainmenuTrans);

            }
        });

        vegbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vegButton);
        nonvegbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nonvegbutton);
/*
        vegbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                final Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VegOptions.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });

        nonvegbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NonVegOptions.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });     */

    }

}
```

Main Initial Layout (**initial_layout.xml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:context="com.techpappy.whattoeat.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:background="@color/cherryRed">

 <!--   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/prefertext_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center">

    </RelativeLayout>     -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Started !"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/cherryRed"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ending scene for MainActivity (**scene1.xml**)

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="What would you prefer ?"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@color/cherryRed"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/wineBrown"
        android:id="@+id/prefertext" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/BtnHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/VegBtnHolder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/vegButton"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/cherryRed"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vegtext"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Vegetarian"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#6B2737"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/NonVegBtnHolder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nonvegbutton"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/cherryRed"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nonvegtext"
                android:layout_width="275dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Non Vegetarian"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#6B2737"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Started !"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/cherryRed"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</merge>
```

How to I apply functionality to these new Veg and Non Veg buttons ?

**Logcat :**

```
06-02 15:02:30.355 31007-31007/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-02 15:02:30.477 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techpappy.whattoeat-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techpappy.whattoeat-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-02 15:02:30.753 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techpappy.whattoeat-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techpappy.whattoeat-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-02 15:02:30.845 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techpappy.whattoeat-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techpappy.whattoeat-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-02 15:02:30.924 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techpappy.whattoeat-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techpappy.whattoeat-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-02 15:02:30.986 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techpappy.whattoeat-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techpappy.whattoeat-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-02 15:02:31.033 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techpappy.whattoeat-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techpappy.whattoeat-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-02 15:02:31.080 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techpappy.whattoeat-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techpappy.whattoeat-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-02 15:02:31.124 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techpappy.whattoeat-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techpappy.whattoeat-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-02 15:02:31.172 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techpappy.whattoeat-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techpappy.whattoeat-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-02 15:02:31.215 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techpappy.whattoeat-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techpappy.whattoeat-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-02 15:02:31.258 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techpappy.whattoeat-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techpappy.whattoeat-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-02 15:02:31.260 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.techpappy.whattoeat-2/lib/arm
06-02 15:02:31.263 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-02 15:02:31.356 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-02 15:02:31.463 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                         --------- beginning of crash
06-02 15:02:31.464 31007-31007/com.techpappy.whattoeat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.techpappy.whattoeat, PID: 31007
                                                                         Theme: themes:{}
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techpappy.whattoeat/com.techpappy.whattoeat.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5449)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.techpappy.whattoeat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6339)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2399)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5449) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: What isn't working about what you tried?

Comment: why didn't you use fragments?

Comment: Are you sure `vegbtn` and `nonvegbtn` is not null? I mean, the view with those ids isn't there yet when the activity was created. Try to do it on the completion of the transition. As for how to do that, look at Android's documentation. I've never use Scene transition before so I can't give you a definite answer.

Comment: @codeMagic I don't exactly know. The app just crashes the moment is launches but when I comment out the vegbtn and nonvegbth code it works and that is why I don't exactly know what to try.

Comment: Then *that* is the answer to my question... *"it crashes"*. In which case you need to post the stacktrace

Comment: I have included my stacktrace and as it turns out @Kurotsuki is right about the nullpointer exception. I would love to try his method only if someone could guide me where to insert the code or what part of my code to replace with that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the `vegbtn` and `nonvegbtn` is null when you try to get the view so any operation to them will resulting `NullPointerException`. Try to add listener to your transition object and do the assignment on the `onTransitionEnd` method.

Maybe like this:

```
mainmenuTrans.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) { }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
        vegbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vegButton);
        nonvegbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nonvegbutton);

        vegbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                final Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,VegOptions.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });

        nonvegbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NonVegOptions.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {}

    @Override
    public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) { }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) { }
});
```

Let me know if it's working. I don't have a full project to test this.

Comment: This is making sense, just one question. Do I add this to my code (keeping previous transition code as it is) or do I replace my code with this. Can you please point out where am I supposed to insert this code in my java file ?

Comment: Placed this code after the OnClickListener code of the btn Button. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating buttons dynamically, then add onClickListener to them and add them to the layout.